# Content Type: Is it possible to have Term reference on Parent Term instead of Vocabulary?

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

I have many Parent Terms with child terms on a Vocabulary. I wanna use one of the parent terms on a content type as option. Is it possible to have a Term Reference field on a Parent Term instead of a Vocabulary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view that show the taxonomy terms that you want to have as options for selection (you will have to manipulate depth).

Then you create an [Entity reference field](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) on your content type that references a taxonomy term. When you add the field it will ask for Entity Selection mode. You select Views (the alternative is Simple), and then you select the view that you created above.

Comment: The entity reference field mentioned is "Entity reference" module?

Comment: @h-l yes it is.

Comment: On the Views, I only see the depth for Content Has Taxonomy Term ID with Depth, which i have to create Content View not Taxonomy. Is there a depth option for Taxonomy Terms View?

Comment: I actually added the Taxonomy Term: Parent Term on Filter Criteria section, and it works.